# Decrypt the following message: 5, 18, 92, 6, 1 [Clues inside]

Tags: cipher

The task is to decode the following: 5, 18, 92, 6, 1

Clues:

1. It's my name  [my name is Jake]
2. "Gliding o'er all, through all, Through Nature, Time, and Space, As a ship on the waters advancing, The voyage of the soul—not life alone, Death, many deaths I'll sing."
3. My first guess (ASCII) was definitely the most on track -- as far as thinking
4. The "cipher" has exactly 118 components

Can you guys help me solve the above using the four clues? Or help me ask the right questions.

Comment: I would have found it much harder as $56, 44, 6, 1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I see 92 I think of uranium.  Decoding this as atomic symbols gives BArUCH.  There are 118 elements [now recognized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element). I don't know what to do with clues 2 and 3.  Clue 2 is a poem by Walt Whitman, for what it's worth.

Comment: I think clue 2 is a [tangential reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliding_Over_All) to Breaking Bad.

Comment: This answer is correct, I appreciate your help on this puzzle. The atomic symbols make up my last name.

Comment: Clue 3, the idea is in thinking how to solve it. Both are Tables that can be used to convert Numbers into Letters, but the Periodic Table gvies BArUCH, while the ASCII table would give something else.  By way of thinking, Using a Famous table that can convert numbers to letters was the way to go, just that the ASCII table was not the correct one to do so.